# Footnote mark in text is not superscript when using reledpar and reledmac with fbb font

Tags: xetex, footnotes, fontspec, reledmac, reledpar

**Note:** Thanks to Alan Munn, just removing the two lines solved this problem. Consider this question solved. I have modified the MWE to reflect this.

How can I make footnote mark appear as superscript in the body text when using `reledpar` and `reledmac` with `fbb` font? I'm compiling with `xelatex`.

As we can see in the MWE, the superscript font feature works nicely, but the `reledmac` footnote is not using it. The number "1" after the word "right" should be in a superscript position, not a normal number.

How can I customize its appearance? The customization code below (commented out makeatletter in MWE) does not change the behavior either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}

% These two lines were the problem. They are not needed.
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Mapping=tex-text,
Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=4.0},
UprightFeatures={StylisticSet=01},
BoldFeatures={StylisticSet=01}
]{fbb}

\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bodyfootmarkB}{%
%    \hbox{{\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}\@nameuse{@thefnmarkB}}}
%}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \Xmaxhnotes[A]{0.6\textheight}
    \maxhnotesX[B]{0.6\textheight}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        left
        \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        right\footnoteB{Very important note.}
    However, these numbers are OK: {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}12345}
        \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{xltxtra}` lines from your code.

Comment: Many thanks! My code had some old baggage. Now the bigger project compiles just as it should without those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fontenc` package should generally never be loaded when using `xelatex` or `lualatex` and therefore loading fonts using `fontspec`.  And the  `xltxtra` package is generally not recommended to be loaded anymore.